# How to check if an array has item/items start with a Number in Swift(iOS 9)

Tags: ios

Let's assume this is my array in swift 2.0:
{"8 Letters", "6 Letters", "9 Letters", "John", "Fredrick"}.
During the App execution, those "X Letters" will be replaced by a name. How can i check if the array still has an item which starts with a number like "8 Letters"? I want to load the level2 of the App, when all those "X Letters" got replaced by a name.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: While you could examine the strings, a more sophisticated approach is to have an array of structs, with a Boolean or enum that indicates the "type". Then when you change an array element, you can set the type appropriately

Comment: Thank you Paulw11. But there is no way to implement the struct logic unless i re-write the whole code. The above mentioned array takes its values from a UILabel located in the View, and that label takes its values from a text file. Each text file has 7 questions which the answers should be guessed by the user, when the user finds the answer for example: Oliver Twist then "11 Letters" will be replaced by "Oliver Twist" in the array. When the user gussess all the seven answers, there will be no more "X Letters" existed in the array, the app can go to level 2 to show another seven questions.

Comment: Better to refactor now than persist with a poor design choice that causes problems later. Your UILabel shouldn't be a source of data, it should only be a view onto your data model

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `enum` with an associated value, here's how I would handle it:

```
enum Whatever {
    case number(Int)
    case value(String)
}

let myArray: [Whatever] = [.number(8), .number(6), .number(9), .value("John"), .value("Frederick")]

myArray.forEach {
    switch $0 {
    case .number(let numberOfLetters):
        // Do something
        break
    case .value(let value):
        // Do something
        break
    }
}
```

This way you're not attempting to parse strings checking for Int's. Let me know if you have any questions. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and cooperation pob21 ! But the problem is, this App has 10 levels. Each level has different words in the array, so the number of letters in one array could be 5, 9 ,8, 4, 3 and in the other would be 7,9,10, 4,8 and so on...How can i predict or mention all of them?

Comment: var clues = answersLabel.text!.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")

Comment: clues[answerPosition] = currentAnswer.text!

Comment: answersLabel.text = clues.joinWithSeparator("\n")

Comment: Now, after the first guess by the user(let's say the guess is "New York") the "clues" array looks like this: ["9 Letters", "12 Letters", "7 Letters", "5 Letters",  "6 Letters", "New York", "10 Letters"]. So the user still needs 6 more guesses to complete the level1. After each successful guess i need to check if "clues" array still have any "X Letters" item left? If No, we go to level 2

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying and I still think this is what you want. If we start with  `[.number(12), .number(7), .number(5), .number(8), .number(10)]` And the user guesses "New York", our array now looks like this `[.number(12), .number(7), .number(5), .value("New York"), .number(10)]` After each guess you just iterate over this array, checking for the existence of `.number`'s, if they're aren't any they can move on to the next level. Do you understand what I'm saying? That simplifies the your architecture.

Comment: Let's say I declare [.number(12), .number(7), .number(5), .number(8), .number(10)] for first level. What about the second level? as its array will be [.number(9), .number(6), .number(10), .number(4), .number(11)] where i declare it? What about third level? as its array will be [.number(12), .number(4), .number(3), .number(9), .number(7)].

Comment: Actually i am not defining any array, the array(named "clues") is taking its values from a label dynamically(var clues = answersLabel.text!.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")). Here is what the user sees in the label at level1: 1. A Biblical skin disease  7 letters  2.Has a Dickinson Twist  6 Letters 3.Hupster heartland  8 Letters 4.Ghosts in residence 7 Letters. The label shows a questions at the left, and a clue at the right. At this point, the "clues" array's items will be the clues provided in the label.

Comment: ...Continue: When the user guess the Leprosy for first question, the label in the View will change to show Leprosy instead of 7 Letters, and "clues" array gets updated to have Leprosy in place of 7 Letters. So you see the array is getting filled based on what is provided in the label, and at different levels you will have different array items,

Comment: Hmm, the concept for what you're trying to do is kind of hard to understand as written text. Could you post a screenshot? I understand you're initial problem i believe, I think my solution still works. It seems like your question now is about proper usage.

Comment: Yes, sure!! I wanted to post a screen shot but I don't know how?